# Erasing from std::list<Value> using a raw pointer to Value?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have an `std::list<Value>` that belongs to a managing construct, handing out `Value *` pointers whenever a factory method is called.  These pointers are passed back to the manager when the `Value` needs to be destroyed.  However, I'm unsure how best to use these pointers to find and erase/remove the element.

```
class ValueManager{
public:

    Value * createValue(ValueDef & def) {
        m_valueList.push_back( Value( def ) );
        return &m_valueList.back();
    }

    void destroyValue(Value * target) {

        // Mystery!  
        // How does one remove/erase a list element
        // with only a pointer to it's value?

    }

private:

    std::list<Value> m_valueList;

};
```

Both `::erase` and `::remove` seem ill fit to the task, one takes an iterator instead of a pointer, and the latter takes an entire value, which can't be done because, in this case, there is no acceptable == comparison method between `Values`, only the pointer can reliably be used to find the target.

My question, is what is the most efficient implementation `destroyValue()` could take on?

Comment: The address you're returning is of the *iterator*, not the value. use the iterator *itself* as the return value (and don't try this with anything besides a true `std::list<>`).

Comment: @WhozCraig - Not sure I follow, it returns the address of the element stored as the last element in list, right?  And yes, I am using a list because it doesn't reallocate nodes, invalidating addresses to memory.

Comment: You should be returning an `std::list<Value>::iterator`. The syntax for using it on the receiving end is the same as a pointer (`*x` will use the dereference operator of the iterator to get at the underlying value). Address-of access will require a litte trickery (`&(*x)`), but still doable. However, now you can use that iterator as direct input for iterator-based operations on the containing `std::list<Value>` as well, for things such as `erase()` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: stop returning raw pointers, and start returning iterators.  Then the user who wants to destroy one will pass in the value received when it was created, just like now.  And dereferencing will still work as it does with a raw pointer.  But erase will also work, and be efficient.

Comment: I wanted to avoid iterators because they require lengthy `std::list<Value>::iterator` declarations in the code that uses it.  Also, it exposes the iterator ability to access other elements that weren't explicitly returned, using `++` for instance, which would cause things to go haywire if used at all.  Is there no way to just use pointers?

Comment: So make a typedef, like `ValueIter`.  That way it's only 2 more characters to type (vs `Value *`).  If you really need to prevent "moving" the returned iterator, just make your own class type instead and return that, and have it contain an iterator and implement `operator*` to support dereferencing.